# Build OpenCV static libraries for iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, static-libraries

I'm trying to build OpenCV **static libraries** from source code for iOS.
How can I do this?

OpenCV provides a python script to build an iOS framework, but it builds an iOS framework (which is not what I want, because it takes 350 MB).